# What does "Service google play" application actually do?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-play-services

First of all "Service google play" (in Russian "Сервисы google play") is **not** play market appication which is used to download and install applications from play market. So what is the problem with it? I spot that "Service google play" (in Russian "Сервисы google play") took about 100Mb (for strange searching data) and cleanuping application data does not help - after several minutes they are magically restored. I wonder - can  it be safely removed (or disabled) from phone? Or it is a system important process?

**Note**

It probably good to provided a link to google play, but I can not find that service (may be english name is different) in play market.

Comment: In response to your note, one does not simply find Google play services/Service Google play by searching the play store.

Answer (score 1):

Added to the exaggerated "Apps may not work if you uninstall Google Play services" from the app's description (see e.g. the [answer of SuperThomasLab](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/126889/16575)):

Many apps found on *Google Play* depend on this, but by far not all. Apps e.g. from *F-Droid* mostly can live without it. One can think of *Google Play Services* as kind of "shared library" for "many things Google".

When using a custom ROM without GApps, it can e.g. be substituted by [migroG GmsCore](https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_GmsCore) – I've just done that on one of my devices :) *[microG](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-microg-gmscore-floss-play-services-t3217616) GmsCore*, as the name-part "Core" suggests, offers the essential services many apps rely on – but without all the overhead Google's app ships with. So it should be much less aggressive towards the device's resources. Please see the linked XDA thread for details and up-to-date information – which also gives you ideas on what *Google Play Services* does:

- **Ads/Analytics API:** will not be covered by *microG*
- **Auth API:** authentication with Google's services. Covered by *microG*
- **Cast API:** in the works (*microG* is still young :)
- **Drive API:** Google Drive stuff (not yet in *microG*)
- **Fitness API:** not (yet) in *microG*
- **Games API:** not (yet) in *microG*
- **Cloud Messaging API:** fully functional in *microG*
- **Location Provider API:** fully functional in *microG*
- **Geofencing API:** not yet supported in *microG*
- **Maps API:** partly implemented in *microG* (work in progress)
- **Plus API:** minimal support with *microG*
- **Wearable API:** work on this has just started in *microG*

From this list you can get an idea what *Google Play Services* include. And from the "state" mentioned toward them for *microG*, you should see why it's more lightweight. I for one hope that, if implemented at all, Fitness + Games at least go to a separate app which one only need to install when needed; I don't need that, so for me it would be [bloatware](/questions/tagged/bloatware) :)

Answer (score 0):

I copy the description from [Google Play Market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms):

> Google Play services is used to update Google apps and apps from
>   Google Play. This component provides core functionality like
>   authentication to your Google services, synchronized contacts, access
>   to all the latest user privacy settings, and higher quality,
>   lower-powered location based services. Google Play services also
>   enhances your app experience. It speeds up offline searches, provides
>   more immersive maps, and improves gaming experiences. Apps may not
>   work if you uninstall Google Play services.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Play Services** is hidden in Google Play. You can find it [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms).

Google Play Services is an app that brings the newest features to older phones, like authentication to Google Services. When you uninstall/disable Google Play Services then most of the apps on your phone won't work properly anymore.

Description copied from Google Play:

> **Google Play services** is used to update Google apps and apps from Google Play.
>   This component provides core functionality like **authentication to your Google services,** **synchronized contacts**, access to all the **latest user privacy settings,** and higher quality, lower-powered **location based services.**
>   Google Play services also enhances your app experience. It speeds up **offline searches**, **provides more immersive maps**, and **improves gaming experiences**.
>   **Apps may not work if you uninstall Google Play services.**

Comment: Added to the exaggerated "Apps may not work if you uninstall Google Play services": Many apps found on *Google Play* depend on this, but by far not all. Apps e.g. from *F-Droid* mostly can live without it. One can think of *Google Play Services* as kind of "shared library" for "many things Google". When using a custom ROM without GApps, it can e.g. be substituted by [migroG GmsCore](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-microg-gmscore-floss-play-services-t3217616) – I've just done that on one of my devices :)